# How to disable Kerberos auth for non valid user

Tags: apache, authentication, kerberos

I have Kerberos on apache 2.2 which is used for SingleSignOn to tomcat application.
If user is authenticated in domain - everything i working fine, credentials are passed through to application and he is automatically logged in (so Kerberos/SSO is running smoothly).

The problem is when user trying to reach website without domain account. He is always asked for credentials (I can avoid that using ErrorDocument 401 site redirect to different tomcat port, but that's not the case).

How to passed it, so user without domain account is passed through apache to tomcat logon site, and user authenticated by Kerberos is automatically logged.

I've tried many thing with apache directives Allow from ..., Deny from, Satisfy All etc., but nothing helped me solve this.

In one scenario I was successfully logged using SSO, but asked for credentials on browser (if not doamin user) in second scenarion I was passed through apache no matter if I was "valid user (domain account)" or not (not domain account).

Here is my current apache location configuration:

```
<Location />
    AuthType                Kerberos
    AuthName                "SSO Login"
    KrbMethodNegotiate      On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd       Off
    KrbAuthRealms           DOMAIN.NAME
    KrbServiceName Any
    Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/keytab
    Require                 valid-user

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary


</Location>
```

PS. In scenario where I used some "Allow from..." and/or "Satisfy" apache directives there was no information in apache debug logs about kerberos authentication try.

PPS. solution from this site is not working: http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/apache-kerberos-authentication
it's always passed me through apache no matter who am I

Many thanks for some hints
Krzysiek